# Android maven plugin - Takes a long time build on every save of a file

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I tried to mavenize my android project using maven-android-plugin but every time I try saving any file it takes a long time to build (build automatically) and another quick save, eclipse does not allow me to edit until the entire compilation completes. The only explicit goal I have specified is generate-sources (I have some AIDLs). But it is frustrating to sit and wait for more than half a minute every time I save for compilation to finish.

The one project that is actually generating the final apk alone takes 1 min 7 seconds (without running tests) to build from command line and there is no way that is good considering I have fairly small number of classes in that project.

Is there someway I can quicken this process?

Answer (score 0):

Since building with Maven consists of several phases, you can manipulate your build time with proper setup. You can find the detailed description of the whole process here:

[Maven build process](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_life_cycle.htm)

With this, you can specifically define your build process and shorten the build times considerably (for example, by turning off tests).